# Calculus Velocity and Acceleration

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

Here's the question:

[image]

I know that:

$a(t) = -9.8$ 

So I integrated the acceleration function to find the velocity:

$v(t) = -9.8t + c$

And because $v(0) = -5$, I can determine that $c = -5$, thus:

$v(t) = -9.8t - 5$

I then integrated the velocity function to find the position:

$s(t) = -4.9t^2 - 5t + c'$

And because at time $t= 0$, the position $s(t=0) = 0$, $c' = 0$, thus:

$s(t) = -4.9t^2 - 5t$

Then, when the ball hits the ground, $s(t) = 30$, so:

$4.9t^2 + 5t + 30 = 0$

This is my working so far and I just wanted to check if I did it right since I was a bit confused by the question. To find $t$ now would I just sub in to the quadratic formula? Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Yes that's it your done solve for t and to get velocity use work-energy theorem or use kinematic equations

Comment: When the ball hits the ground $s(t) = -30$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all of it is correct, only the last equation is wrong:

The ground is 30 meters *UNDER* the bridge, so you want the time at which the value od $s(t)$ is equal to $-30$.

---

It will be very helpful for you to understand why I was able to very quickly notice that something is wrong with your solution. Here is the thought train that got me there:

- OK, looks pretty much OK, the OP found $s(t)$ to be some sort of quadratic expression in $t$.
- I see, now he's solving the equation $s(t)=30$
- But wait, that means he's solving an equation $c_1 t^2 + c_2 t + 30 = 0$! But that's no good! Because $c_1$ and $c_2$ are both positive, $c_1 t^2 + c_2 t + 30$ will be positive if the time is positive!

  - This is not possible: from common sense, I *know* that the ball must hit the ground. There must have been a sign mixup somewhere.

Comment: Yeah I must've mixed it up somewhere, thanks for the answer!